# i need to loook for amount of properties in object , can not find the mistake

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

```
function propsCount(){ 
       let mentor = { 
          course: "JS fundamental", 
          duration: 3,
          direction: "web-development"
       };

       console.log(Object.keys(mentor).length);
       console.log(propsCount(mentor));
}
```

Comment: There is a number of things are likely wrong here. Please may you share examples of how you want to use the function and what it should output

Comment: Well for one, you're not calling your function. You are calling it from inside of itself, not outside, so it may be just that.

Answer (score 1):

```
function propsCount(){ 
       let mentor = { 
          course: "JS fundamental", 
          duration: 3,
          direction: "web-development"
       };

       console.log(Object.keys(mentor).length);
      // console.log(propsCount(mentor)); this function is recursive 
}
```

`console.log(propsCount(mentor));` this console function is recursive so it never gonna end so it will give you error of `maximum stack` . try rmove it all working fine. use return to get it property count.

try this :

```
function propsCount(obj){ 
     return Object.keys(obj).length;
}

 var propertyLength = propsCount({course: "JS fundamental", duration: 3,direction: "web-development"});
// or 
//let mentor = { 
//          course: "JS fundamental", 
//          duration: 3,
//          direction: "web-development"
//       };
// var propertyLength = propsCount(mentor);
// Or in ES6
// const propsCount = obj => Object.keys(obj).length; 
console.log(propertyLength);
```

Comment: Or in ES6 `const propsCount = obj => Object.keys(obj).length;`

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but I made this code, maybe its right

```
function propsCount(){ 
        let mentor = { 
            course: "JS fundamental", 
            duration: 3,
            direction: "web-development"
         };

        return Object.keys(mentor).length;
    }

   console.log(propsCount());
```

The function creates an mentor object, and then returns the length of the object. Then the console.log returns the length